# Renders LaTeX code in UILabel/UITextfield natively on iOS

Tags: ios, swift, latex

I want to render LaTeX in my application. I have tried [iOSMath](https://github.com/kostub/iosMath) and [iOSLatex](https://cocoapods.org/pods/iOSLaTeX).

The problem is iOS Math does not support latex with text while iOS Latex renders latex on a WkWebview and the takes screenshot of it and return an image.

Do we have a native renderer for LaTeX (on iOS)?

I am trying to render

> Solve this equation (\left{\begin{matrix} 3x + 2y - 11 = 0 \ 2x + 3y - 9 = 0 \end{matrix}\right.)

Comment: If you mean by *native* from Apple, then no, Apple does not provide any official public API for LaTex rendering.

Comment: By native, I want to say if Latex can be used as attributed string as iOSMath does, but it does not provide support for all latex tokens.

Comment: I posted a solution that uses iosMath [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53978178/swift-display-latex-math-expressions-inline/57277287#57277287)

Answer (score 4):

You can use KatexMathe View

[you can download this library](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1jUVe5MjnDz1HJc2ttInmtSKoqSbvhy5i)

[image: Example here]

```
//MARK:- IBOutlet

@IBOutlet weak var webViewQuestion: KatexMathView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.webViewQuestion.loadLatex("your string")
}

extension ReadQuestionVC : WKNavigationDelegate {

public func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {       
       self.webViewQuestionHC.constant = 10 //Default constant height
       self.setContaintSizeWebView(webView: webViewQuestion, constantSize: self.webViewQuestionHC)

}

func setContaintSizeWebView(webView:WKWebView,constantSize:NSLayoutConstraint){
    webView.evaluateJavaScript("document.readyState", completionHandler: { (complete, error) in
        if complete != nil {
            webView.evaluateJavaScript("Math.max(document.body.scrollHeight, document.body.offsetHeight, document.documentElement.clientHeight, document.documentElement.scrollHeight, document.documentElement.offsetHeight)", completionHandler: { (height, error) in
                constantSize.constant = height as! CGFloat
                webView.sizeToFit()
                self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
            })
        }

    })
}
}
```

Comment: I have already used iOSLatex which does the same. It does not solve the problem.